# How to add an array of annotations to a d3 barchart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've managed to draw a barchart (it's inverted I know :)) for each year of data by reading in the CSV data and then using `d3.nest()` to group the data for each date per year, see block [here](http://bl.ocks.org/eoiny/a1169104fd3d0b78a2b60a2f099e0391) or blockbuilder [here](http://blockbuilder.org/eoiny/a1169104fd3d0b78a2b60a2f099e0391). 
However I'm am now trying to append notes from my `annotations` array to each chart and I'm stuck.

One approach I'm trying is to `selectAll(".charts")` and to append my nested annotations array i.e. `annotationsPerYear`. But I'm finding it difficult to join my annotationsPerYear key with my charts and then to iterate and append the notes for each year onto the correct chart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on nested selections for this. You're already using nested selection with this bit:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
```

The above binds different data to each of the 3 SVGs created earlier. It does this by calling the `function(d)` 3 times, and returns a different `d.values` each time.

You can do a similar thing to bind and create a different set of annotations in each SVG. You need a function (passed to `data()`) that returns the applicable annotations per chart, but this time you don't have something pre-computed like `d.values`. Instead, you have to extract the applicable annotations out of `annotations` array, using `filter()`:

```
svg.selectAll(".annotation")
  .data(function(d) {
    // return annotations whose key matches d's key
    return annotations.filter(function(a) { return a.key == d.key; });
  })
```

Then you can use `enter()` and `append()` as you've done for the bars to create the text and position it. I'm not sure how you intend to lay it out, but altogether you want something like this:

```
svg.selectAll(".annotation")
  .data(function(d) {
    return annotations.filter(function(a) { return a.key == d.key; });
  })
.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "annotation")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.xPos); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.yPos; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.note; })
```

See:

- [Updated block](http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d55278904c296a373af7aeb3ac188ad2)
- [Updated blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/d55278904c296a373af7aeb3ac188ad2)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. And yes that's how I was going to lay it out once I got the keys matching up. I have noticed a separate problem now with leap years e.g. 2016 data includes 29 Feb. I'm guessing this can be tackled where I set the x.domain? Or should I post a new question here?

Comment: Yeah that's a separate, non-trivial issue, probably worthy of its own post. Yeah, it should be addressed through the x scale, either by switching to a time scale or by ensuring that the ordinal scale's domain includes the 29th. The former is complicated (because positioning/sizing the bars becomes more involved), the latter means the 29th will appear on every year (just without a bar on non-leap years). So it kind of depends on what you're trying to achieve.